# ORA-04091: table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert

I created a trigger to insert a log in a table when an insert is made on another table.

This is the code of the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER scheme1.Inserting_Feed 
          AFTER INSERT ON scheme2.payments FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO scheme2.db-logger(ID, TECHNOLOGY, WORKFLOW, NAME_EVENT, TIME_EVENT)
  VALUES(:NEW.id,'Repository','UP',(select repo.name 
                                      from scheme1.repository repo 
                                      join scheme2.payments pay 
                                        on repo.id = pay.repository_id
                                     where repo.id = NEW.repository_id), SYSDATE);
END;
```

I try to run this trigger but when I make an insert on the table payments I get following error:

> Error MT101-GENERAL_LOAD_ERROR: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   ORA-04091: table scheme1.payments is mutating, trigger/function may
>   not see it ORA-06512: at "scheme1.Inserting_Feed", line 2 ORA-04088:
>   error during execution of trigger 'scheme1.Inserting_Feed'

What I understand is that the error says the table is changing, but the trigger doesn't see it. How does this come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why join to the scheme2.payments table in the subquery in the insert statement? Couldn't you just do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER scheme1.inserting_feed
  AFTER INSERT
  ON scheme2.payments
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO scheme2.db_logger (id,
                                 technology,
                                 workflow,
                                 name_event,
                                 time_event)
    VALUES      ( :new.id,
                  'Repository',
                  'UP',
                  (SELECT repo.name
                   FROM   scheme1.repository repo
                   WHERE  repo.id = :new.repository_id),
                  SYSDATE);
END;
/
```

Comment: with this code I get a null value in my trigger insert, my field can't be nullable so it throws an exception